# Is there an inference rule with premise neg X with neg X OR Y and conclusion Y?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is there an inference rule with a premise of $$\neg X,\neg X \lor Y $$ with the conclusion
$$Y$$

How do I apply resultion as inference rule on the following for proposition logic formulas: 
$$\neg X,\neg X \lor Y, \neg Y$$

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The first is an invalid argument.

Comment: what do you mean? premise: X∨Y and conclusion Y is possible?

Comment: ok, what does this mean for my resolution calculation if I end up with the three formulas (¬X,¬X∧Y,¬Y) if I want to show that omega is contradiction?

Comment: An invalid argument is one in which you can have true premises and a false conclusion. Since that is possible here, your first argument of $\neg X,\; \neg X \lor Y,\; \therefore Y$ is invalid. There should be no inference rule that lets you do that!

Comment: Also, what is omega?

Comment: omega is my knowledge base with the negated query. Yes, i think the same!

Comment: @user3352632 You switched from $\vee$ to $\wedge$ in the middle term.  Which is it? $~\neg X, \neg X\raise{0.25ex}\vee Y\vdash Y$ *is not* valid.  $~\neg X, \neg X\raise{0.25ex}\wedge Y\vdash Y$ *is* valid,

Comment: Maybe he means something more interesting: $ X, \neg X\raise{0.25ex}\vee Y\vdash Y$, a way to state modus ponens.

Comment: So the one with AND was wrong. I corrected it. The correct one is: $$\neg X,\neg X \lor Y, \neg Y$$. I think modus ponens needs an implication? I have no. I think there is an error in the excercise.

Answer (score 1):

No, that would not be valid.   $\neg X, \neg X\vee Y\nvdash Y$.    The premises just say assume: "$X$ is definitely false, $Y$ *may* also be true."   So they don't infer that $Y$ *is* true.

However $\neg X,\neg X\wedge Y \vdash Y$ *is* valid . Under the assumption that $\neg X$ and $Y$ are true, then of course $Y$ is true.

Which did you actually mean?

Comment: I updated the question, I mean the first one.